# 2 unbound variable errors in my scheme program

Tags: list, sorting, variables, scheme

I have a question about two unbound variable errors I'm getting with my program in scheme: ';Unbound variable: temp' and ';Unbound variable: record'.

I'm ultimately trying to make a sort function to sort my roster (a list of student info with each element being a sublist) by ID in ascending order. Each sublist of roster contains 3 elements: ID number (string of digits), name (string of chars) and grade (int) as its own list. The ID number is the first element of each sublist in roster. At the moment I am making a 'smallest' helper function to return the smallest ID number (as record) of all the sublists in roster.

Quick Side Note: I am not allowed to use any set! functions or do-loops, or any built-in sort functions.

My goal for 'smallest' at the moment is to append roster to a local variable 'temp' because I don't want roster to change when it returns from the function. Before I can do this I have to get my ';unbound variable: record' I tried defining record to be an int before it is passed into my 'smallest' function with this code:

```
((= n 3)
 (begin  
   (display "\n\tOption 3.")
   (display "\nDisplay Roster by ID")
   (display "\nsmallest record is: ")
   (lambda (record) (* record record) 100)
   (smallest roster record)
   (menu roster)))

(define smallest
  (lambda (roster record) 
    ((append roster temp)
     (cond ((or (null? temp) (equals (length(temp)) 1)) record) 
           ((< (car(car temp)) (car(car(cdr temp)))) 
            (if (or (null? record) (> record (car(car temp)))) 
                (cons (car(car temp)) record) 
                record)
            (smallest (cdr temp) record))
           (else (smallest (cdr temp) record))))))
```

Comment: Generally if you post a link to the image (e.g., upload it to imgur), someone with enough rep will post it for you.

Comment: `(lambda (record) (* record record) 100)` is an unnamed function that squares a number, throws it away, and then returns 100. You never use it for anything. And `(append roster temp)` and `(cons (car(car temp)) record)` create *new* lists - nothing is modified (or would create them, if a thing called "temp" existed). It looks like you're already familiar with some other language; it's easier to learn Scheme if you pretend that you aren't and start learning from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Before using a variable you need to declare it (for example, using `let` or declaring it as a parameter of the function where you are using it). I see in your code this line:

`(smallest roster record)`

In which you use 2 undefined variables (unbound variables), so that is the reason of your 2 errors.

To solve it, first use `let` to declare the variables, and later you can use them.

If you don't know how to use `let` or `let*` see this: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html

Comment: I tried this yet I get the error ';Ill-formed special form: (let (record 1000) record)'. I put '(let (record 1000) record)' where you see '(lambda (record) (* record record) 100)'

Comment: @SasheemSnell it's `(let ((record 1000) (other-variable other-value)) expression-that-uses-the-values)`

Comment: @Sylwester I'm sorry, what do you mean by other-variable and other-value?

Comment: @Sylwester Oh I see, my parentheses .. Thank you

Comment: @SasheemSnell I just added a second variable to show the parentheses.. its `(let (bindings ...) body ...)`

Answer (score 0):

#### Disclaimer

Increasingly, I find it easier to debug programs when I build them up systematically using the methods of Ableson and Sussman...i.e. thinking in terms of layered languages. YMMV.

### Implementation

I've used `#lang racket` but called a standard Scheme function for string comparison on `record:ID`. I've provided function signatures (though not checked them) because the implementation uses higher order functions in the language building process.

```
#lang racket/base
(require srfi/13)

;;; Make a language for records

(define ID car)
(define name cadr)
(define grade caddr)

;; [any? any? -> boolean] [listof any? -> any?] -> [listof any? -> any?]
(define (make-record-compare-function predicate field)
  (lambda (record1 record2)
    (predicate (field record1) (field record2))))


;;; Make a language for comparing records
;;; This is a parital implementation

(define ID<?
  (make-record-compare-function string< ID))

;; record record -> record
(define (return-record-with-smaller-ID record1 record2)
  (if (ID<? record1 record2)
      record1
      record2))

;;; Make a language for searching rosters
;;; This is a partial implementation

;; [any? any? -> any?] -> [listof any? -> any?]
(define (make-roster-search comparator)
  (define  (inner roster best-match)
    (if (null? roster)
      best-match
      (inner (cdr roster)
             (comparator best-match
                         (car roster)))))
  (lambda (roster)
    (inner (cdr roster)
           (car roster))))
```

All the magic happens within the internal function `inner`. It's `best-match` argument carries the local state containing the smallest record found so far.

### Usage

```
racket@29661598.rkt> (define record1 (list "02" "Sasheem" 23))
racket@29661598.rkt> (define record2 (list "34" "Ben" -42))
racket@29661598.rkt> (define smallest (make-roster-search
                       return-record-with-smaller-ID))
racket@29661598.rkt> (smallest (list record1 record2))
'("02" "Sasheem" 23)
racket@29661598.rkt> (smallest (list record2 record1))
'("02" "Sasheem" 23)
racket@29661598.rkt> (smallest (list record1 record1))
'("02" "Sasheem" 23)
```